# Unable to send email in PHP through Html Form

Tags: php, html, email

I design and developed one website in which I have one contact form. I wanted to send inquiry email through contact form. But I am getting following error in console. I tried on local system as well as on server.

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///E:/clients/website/contact.php' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.
```

Here is my HTML Code :

```
<form id="contactform" action="contact.php" name="contactform" method="post" class="form-validation" autocomplete="off">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                <div class="single-input">
                                    <input type="text" placeholder="First Name*" name="Fname" id="Fname">
                                </div> <!-- /.single-input -->
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                <div class="single-input">
                                    <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name*" name="Lname" id="Lname">
                                </div> <!-- /.single-input -->
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                <div class="single-input">
                                    <input type="email" placeholder="Your Email*" name="email" id="email">
                                </div> <!-- /.single-input -->
                            </div>
                        </div> <!-- /.row -->
                        <div class="single-input">
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Subject" name="sub" id="subject">
                        </div> <!-- /.single-input -->
                        <textarea placeholder="Write Message" name="message" id="message"></textarea>


                        <button type="submit" value="SEND" id="submit" class="tran3s p-color-bg">Send Message</button>
                    </form>
```

Here is contact.php

```
<?php
if(!$_POST) exit;

// Email address verification, do not edit.
function isEmail($email) {
    return(preg_match("/^[-_.[:alnum:]]+@((([[:alnum:]]|[[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]-]*[[:alnum:]])\.)+(com|coop|cr|cs)$|(([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5])\.){3}([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5]))$/i",$email));
}

if (!defined("PHP_EOL")) define("PHP_EOL", "\r\n");

$Fname     = $_POST['Fname'];
$Lname     = $_POST['Lname'];
$email    = $_POST['email'];
$subject  = $_POST['subject'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $message = stripslashes($message);
}

$address = "sales@abc.com";

$e_subject = 'You\'ve been contacted by ' . $Fname . '.';

$e_body = "You have been contacted by $Fname with regards to $subject, their additional message is as follows." . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
$e_content = "\"$message\"" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
$e_reply = "You can contact $Fname via email, $email";

$msg = wordwrap( $e_body . $e_content . $e_reply, 70 );

$headers = "From: $email" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable" . PHP_EOL;

if(mail($address, $e_subject, $msg, $headers)) {

    // Email has sent successfully, echo a success page.

    echo "<fieldset>";
    echo "<div id='success_page'>";
    echo "<h1>Email Sent Successfully.</h1>";
    echo "<p>Thank you <strong>$Fname</strong>, your message has been submitted to us.</p>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</fieldset>";

} else {

    echo 'ERROR!';

}
```

Comment: View the page through a web server, so the URL starts with `http`. It looks like you're just opening the file in a browser, so the URL starts with `file`

Comment: I tried but i am getting exception like    `http://contact.php/ net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`

Comment: It would be `http://localhost/contact.php` or `http://yourdomainname.com/contact.php` . It just depends on if you're trying to use it on your live server or your local dev server. The local dev server sometimes uses another port, so check with whatever software you're using.

Answer (score 0):

`XMLHttpRequest` does not support `file` scheme.

You could try this:

**Solution 1**: Use http/https instead of local file.

I would never use the file protocol for server-side files, if you need to test your .php files locally, it's better to use a localhost (like XAMPP) and test your code.

**Solution 2** (don't skip the solution 1): Try this if solution 1 didn't work, but please don't use the `file` protocol (otherwise it won't work anyway).

Try to add the following header to the HTTP response:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

The header above will allow your scripts to read the response regardless of the origin.

**Note:** Don't use `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` on your production code, otherwise you're exposing your website to security vulnerabilities.